# Definition of decidable sentence

Tags: logic, algorithms

Let $P(n)$ is a sentence which mentions natural number $n \in \mathbb{n}$

For example, "$n > 5$" or "There is no $n$ such that  $3^n+4^n=5^n$ "  can be $P(n)$.

I want to define a set A as a set of decidable sentences.

> $P(n)\in A$  if and only if
>
> There is a Turing machine $M(n)$ such that $M(n)=0$ $\leftrightarrow$
>   $P(n)$ is true

For example, let $P(n)$ : "There are two primes $p$ and $q$ such that $p+q=2n$", then $P(n)\in A$

However, some says that this definition is not good because I use the term "true."

How can I define the set A without using the term "true"?

And what's the usual name of the set A? I don't think that 'decidable sentence' is not the proper name.

Comment: I think the term you want is *recursive set*. Note that your "there is no $n$ $\dots$" is not an example, the variable $n$ does not occur free there.

Comment: Thank you @AndréNicolas . Hence, How can I change my definition with "Recursive set"?

Comment: You can look up formal definitions. We want $P(n)$ to be a **formula** (not a sentence) with a free variable $n$, as in your first example. Just remove the second example, as I mentioned, the occurrence of $n$ there is not free, since it is quantified, there is an implicit $\lnot \exists n$. You could however just say if you wish $3^n+4^n\ne 5^n$, without the there does not exist. Other good examples are $n$ is prime, $n$ is a sum of two squares, and so on.